# How to find value then copy entire row to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have three worksheets "School_shipped_orders" "All_shipped_orders_with_batch" and "School_shipped_batch".

I want to use the order numbers in "School_shipped_orders" column A  to search for the same number in "All_shipped_orders_with_batch" column C.
If there is a match then cut the entire rows with match from "All_shipped_orders_with_batch" and paste to the last row in the "School_shipped_batch" sheet.

My code goes into loop and never ends and copies only first match for every order. I want to copy all matches found.

```vb
Dim Cell        As Range
Dim ID          As Variant
Dim NextRow     As Long
Dim WksDst      As Worksheet
Dim WksLog      As Worksheet
Dim WksSrc      As Worksheet

Set WksLog = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("School_shipped_orders")
Set WksSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All_shipped_orders_with_batch")
Set WksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("School_shipped_batch")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

NextRow = WksDst.UsedRange.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row + 1
    
For Each ID In WksLog.Range("A2:A1000").Cells
    Set Cell = WksSrc.Range("C2:C1000").Cells.Find(ID, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, False, False, False)
    If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
        With Cell.EntireRow
            .Copy WksDst.Cells(NextRow, "A")
            .Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            NextRow = NextRow + 1
        End With
    End If
Next ID
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Backup Data

- The following will try to find values of column `A` of `Lookup Worksheet`, in column `C` of `Source Worksheet`. For each found value, it will add (combine) the current cell in `Source Worksheet` to the `Combined Range`. Finally, the entire rows of the `Combined Range` will be copied to `Destination Worksheet` and deleted from `Source Worksheet` in one go.
- Note that this (less efficient, slower) is different than the 'usual' approach when the values of the `Source Worksheet` are matched (using `Application.Match`) against the values in `Lookup Worksheet` (when it is assumed that the `Lookup Worksheet` contains unique (less) values).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub backupData()
    
    ' Constants
    Const sName As String = "All_shipped_orders_with_batch"
    Const sFirst As String = "C2"
    Const lName As String = "School_shipped_orders"
    Const lFirst As String = "A2"
    Const dName As String = "School_shipped_batch"
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    With sws.Range(sFirst)
        Set sCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Resize(sCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    'Debug.Print srg.Address
    
    ' Lookup
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets(lName)
    Dim lrg As Range
    Dim lCell As Range
    With lws.Range(lFirst)
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set lrg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    'Debug.Print lrg.Address
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dCell As Range
    Set dCell = dws.UsedRange.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If dCell Is Nothing Then
        Set dCell = dws.Range("A1")
    Else
        Set dCell = dws.Cells(dCell.Row + 1, "A")
    End If
    'Debug.Print dCell.Address
    
    ' Find & Combine
    
    Dim crg As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    
    For Each lCell In lrg.Cells
        Set sCell = Nothing
        Set sCell = srg.Find( _
            lCell.Value, srg.Cells(srg.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
        If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = sCell.Address
            Do
                If crg Is Nothing Then
                   Set crg = sCell
                Else
                    Set crg = Union(crg, sCell)
                End If
                Set sCell = srg.FindNext(sCell)
            Loop Until sCell.Address = FirstAddress
        End If
    Next lCell
        
    ' Cut (Copy & Delete)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If Not crg Is Nothing Then
        'Debug.Print crg.Address
        crg.EntireRow.Copy dCell
        crg.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing code.  Thank for explanation. Hmm any ideas  how to make check if  values on destination sheet are already there and don't copy row. ?

Comment: Tiny little details make quite a difference, don't they? It's kind of complicated and out of the scope of your question. You should ask another one. Try to include more detail, e.g. explain why there would be an already backed up row when you have previously deleted it, will you delete it if it already exists (you won't copy)... You could post a link to the new question in your comments so the previously interested contributors (incl. me) may find it more easily. You should rather loop through `Source` and use `Match` to find it in `Lookup` and use a similar `Match` to find it in `Dest`...

Comment: Thank You. Just still learning things here and overall  !